# Using this.updateStyles() after this.classList.add()

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a component like this (tiny, short and sweet):

---

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style include="my-shared-styles">

      :host(.main-ent) {
        --primary-color: var(--paper-blue-600);
      }
      :host(.main-all) {
        --primary-color: var(--paper-purple-700);
      }
    </style>

    <an-element-using-primary-color></an-element-using-primary-color>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        siteInfo: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true,
      },

      attached: function() {

        console.log("SITEINFO (SHORT):", this.siteInfo.short );

        this.classList.add('main-' + this.siteInfo.short);
        //this.async( function() {
          this.updateStyles();
        //});

      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem I am having is that without that `this.async()`, *sometimes* (say one time out of 8) `this.updateStyles()` doesn't seem to work: the primary colour stays "wrong".
I am not even 10000% sure the problem is solved with `this.async()`, or only mitigated.

So...

- What's the root of the problem?
- Does `this.async()` actually fix it?
- If not, what does?

Answer (score -1):

Try to clean up your CSS Classes. First Remove the one you don´t need anymore then set the new one.

```
this.classList.remove('unneeded_class');
this.classList.add('new_class');
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted without any explanation? That's not helpful. If this is not a good solution, I want to know why.